# How can I remove the default wallpaper of a custom ROM?

Tags: lock-screens, custom-roms, home-screen, customization, wallpaper

Each time in my `AOSP` **custom** ROM, I change the `default` wallpaper for `home` and `lock screen` into another one, they get `reset` after a `reboot`. How can I remove these wallpapers from the system, so they can't come back?

[image]

Here is my ROM info:

[image]

Comment: The current wallpaper files should be located here: `/data/system/users/0/wallpaper*` Not sure what partition this directory belongs to or when it is written.

Comment: @Robert https://prnt.sc/v8ucfo / https://prnt.sc/v8udw0  I didn't find them.

Comment: The default wallpaper is normally found in the frameworks/base/core/res/res/drawable-nodpi/default_wallpaper.png, but can be overwritten by OEM overlays found in device/vendor.

Comment: @Aayush tried hard but didn't find the path you've referred.